# Access grand child elements from the DOM in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

How would i go about accessing grand child elements within in a ul structure such as with jquery:

```
<ul>
   <li>Sample</li>
   <li>Sample</li>
   <li>Sample</li>
   <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Need to Get access to this li</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Sample</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be a simple

```
$('ul li ul li')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ul element in `root`, then `root.find("li ul li")` will get you the li element you want (and all others at that level).

Answer (score 0):

Given your example markup.

```
$('ul ul li');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li ul li')
```

Would be the code in jQuery.

You can test this with:

```
$('ul li ul li').css({fontWeight: 'bold'});
```

Answer (score 0):

try [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('ul:eq(1) > li')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EDE7J/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not the grand child elements, because that would be:

```
li > li
     +-- grand child
+-- child
```

Rather you want the child's descendants:

```
li li
   +-- descendant (not necessarily immediate)
+-- child
```

To anchor it to your top `ul`:

```
ul > li li
```